# Object not found error when passing model formula to another function

Tags: r, formula

I have a weird problem with R that I can't seem to work out.

I've tried to write a function that performs K-fold cross validation for a model chosen by the stepwise procedure in R. (I'm aware of the issues with stepwise procedures, it's purely for comparison purposes) :)

Now the issue is, that if I define the function parameters (linmod,k,direction) and run the contents of the function, it works flawlessly. BUT, if I run it as a function, I get an error saying the datas.train object can't be found.

I've tried stepping through the function with debug() and the object clearly exists, but R says it doesn't when I actually run the function. If I just fit a model using lm() it works fine, so I believe it's a problem with the step function in the loop, while inside a function. (try commenting out the step command, and set the predictions to those from the ordinary linear model.)

```
#CREATE A LINEAR MODEL TO TEST FUNCTION
lm.cars <- lm(mpg~.,data=mtcars,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)


#THE FUNCTION
cv.step <- function(linmod,k=10,direction="both"){
  response <- linmod$y
  dmatrix <- linmod$x
  n <- length(response)
  datas <- linmod$model
  form <- formula(linmod$call)

  # generate indices for cross validation
  rar <- n/k
  xval.idx <- list()
  s <- sample(1:n, n) # permutation of 1:n
  for (i in 1:k) {
    xval.idx[[i]] <- s[(ceiling(rar*(i-1))+1):(ceiling(rar*i))]
  }

  #error calculation
  errors <- R2 <- 0

  for (j in 1:k){
     datas.test <- datas[xval.idx[[j]],]
       datas.train <- datas[-xval.idx[[j]],]
       test.idx <- xval.idx[[j]]

       #THE MODELS+
       lm.1 <- lm(form,data= datas.train)
       lm.step <- step(lm.1,direction=direction,trace=0)

      step.pred <- predict(lm.step,newdata= datas.test)
        step.error <- sum((step.pred-response[test.idx])^2)
        errors[j] <- step.error/length(response[test.idx])

        SS.tot <- sum((response[test.idx] - mean(response[test.idx]))^2)
        R2[j] <- 1 - step.error/SS.tot
  }

  CVerror <- sum(errors)/k
  CV.R2 <-  sum(R2)/k

  res <- list()
  res$CV.error <- CVerror
  res$CV.R2 <- CV.R2

return(res)
}


#TESTING OUT THE FUNCTION
cv.step(lm.cars)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: There seems to be a scoping problem, where `step(lm.1,direction=direction,trace=0)` cannot find `datas.train`, as you already know. I can't see the cause of the problem myself. Assigning `datas.train` as a global variable is a work-around, but not a particularly satisfactory one (`datas.train <<- datas[-xval.idx[[j]],]`). Perhaps this should be migrated to StackOverflow?

Comment: Specifically, the call to `add1(fit, scope$add, scale = scale, trace = trace, k = k, ...)` in `step()` throws the error, where `add1()` is `stats:::add1.lm`.

Comment: @jthetzel, Indeed. One way I solved a similar problem but for another function call inside a loop was to assign it globally.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you created your formula, `lm.cars`, in was assigned its own environment. This environment stays with the formula unless you explicitly change it. So when you extract the formula with the `formula` function, the original environment of the model is included.

I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology here, but I think you need to explicitly change the environment for the formula inside your function:

```
cv.step <- function(linmod,k=10,direction="both"){
  response <- linmod$y
  dmatrix <- linmod$x
  n <- length(response)
  datas <- linmod$model
  .env <- environment() ## identify the environment of cv.step

  ## extract the formula in the environment of cv.step
  form <- as.formula(linmod$call, env = .env) 

  ## The rest of your function follows
```

Comment: That works. I will have to look in to this environment stuff. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 14):

Another problem that can cause this is if one passes a `character` (string `vector`) to `lm` instead of a `formula`. `vector`s have no `environment`, and so when `lm` converts the `character` to a `formula`, it apparently also has no `environment` instead of being automatically assigned the local environment. If one then uses an object as weights that is not in the data argument `data.frame`, but is in the local function argument, one gets a `not found` error. This behavior is not very easy to understand. It is probably a bug.

Here's a minimal reproducible example. This function takes a `data.frame`, two variable names and a vector of weights to use.

```
residualizer = function(data, x, y, wtds) {
  #the formula to use
  f = "x ~ y" 

  #residualize
  resid(lm(formula = f, data = data, weights = wtds))
}

residualizer2 = function(data, x, y, wtds) {
  #the formula to use
  f = as.formula("x ~ y")

  #residualize
  resid(lm(formula = f, data = data, weights = wtds))
}

d_example = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
weightsvar = runif(10)
```

And test:

```
> residualizer(data = d_example, x = "x", y = "y", wtds = weightsvar)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'wtds' not found

> residualizer2(data = d_example, x = "x", y = "y", wtds = weightsvar)
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
 0.8986584 -1.1218003  0.6215950 -0.1106144  0.1042559  0.9997725 -1.1634717  0.4540855 -0.4207622 -0.8774290
```

It is a very subtle bug. If one goes into the function environment with `browser`, one can see the weights vector just fine, but it somehow is not found in the `lm` call!

The bug becomes even harder to debug if one used the name `weights` for the weights variable. In this case, since `lm` can't find the weights object, it defaults to the function `weights()` from **base** thus throwing an even stranger error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = f, data = data, weights = weights,  : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'
```

Don't ask me how many hours it took me to figure this out.

Comment: I just encountered this issue using parLapply from parallel. I was passing a formula created outside of the parLapply which apparently came with its own environement. when trying to specify weights, the argument wasn't recognized. the solution was to turn the formula back to a character then back to a formula (in the parLapply function) which created the formula in the local environment. This is quite strange and is worth looking at by the R developers. I never would have figured it out if it weren't for this comment.

Comment: I have spent hours with this same exact issue, thanks for describing it so clearly.