# Use ddply within a function and include variable of interest as an argument

Tags: r, plyr

I am relatively new to R, and trying to use ddply & summarise from the plyr package. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function) almost, but not quite, answers my question. I could use some additional explanation/clarification.

My problem:

I want to create a simple function to summarize descriptive statistics, by group, for a given variable. Unlike the linked post, I would like to include the variable of interest as an argument to the function. As has already been discussed on this site, this works:

```
require(plyr)

ddply(mtcars, ~ cyl, summarise,
  mean = mean(hp),
  sd   = sd(hp),
  min  = min(hp),
  max  = max(hp)
)
```

But this doesn't:

```
descriptives_by_group <- function(dataset, group, x)
{
  ddply(dataset, ~ group, summarise,
    mean = mean(x),
    sd   = sd(x),
    min  = min(x),
    max  = max(x)
  )
}

descriptives_by_group(mtcars, cyl, hp)
```

Because of the volume of data with which I am working, I would like to be able to have a function that allows me to specify the variable of interest to me as well as the dataset and grouping variable.

I have tried to edit the various solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function) to address my problem, but I don't understand the code well enough to do it successfully.

The original poster used the following example dataset:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(0,0,1,1)
c = c(5,6,7,8)
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
sv = c("b")
```

With the desired output:

```
  b Ave
1 0 1.5
2 1 3.5
```

And the solution endorsed by Hadley was:

```
myFunction <- function(x, y){
NewColName <- "a"
z <- ddply(x, y, .fun = function(xx,col){
                         c(Ave = mean(xx[,col],na.rm=TRUE))}, 
           NewColName)
return(z)
}
```

Where `myFunction(df, sv)` returns the desired output.

I tried to break down the code piece-by-piece to see if, by getting a better understanding of the underlying mechanics, I could modify the code to include an argument to the function that would pass to what, in this example, is "NewColName" (the variable you want to get information about). But I am not having any success. My difficulty is that I do not understand what is happening with `(xx[,col])`. I know that mean(xx[,col]) should be taking the mean of the column with index `col` for the data frame `xx`. But I don't understand where the anonymous function is reading those values from.

Could someone please help me parse this? I've wasted hours on a trivial task I could accomplish easily with very repetitive code and/or with subsetting, but I got hung up on trying to make my script more simple and elegant, and on understanding the "whys" of this problem and its solution(s).

PS I have looked into the describeBy function from the psych package, but as far as I can tell, it does not let you specify the variable(s) you want to return values for, and consequently does not solve my problem.

Comment: I"m not sure I understand. `ddply` accepts a character vector of grouping variables. As in, `ddply(data,c('var1','var2'),...)`.

Comment: Also take a look at `colwise`

Comment: The problem was getting the third argument to be passed into `summarise`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just moved a couple things around in the example function you gave and showed how to get more than one column back out.  Does this do what you want?

```
myFunction2 <- function(x, y, col){
z <- ddply(x, y, .fun = function(xx){
                         c(mean = mean(xx[,col],na.rm=TRUE),
                         max = max(xx[,col],na.rm=TRUE) ) })
return(z)
}

myFunction2(mtcars, "cyl", "hp")
```

Answer (score 5):

(More of a comment than an answer. I had the same level of difficulty as you when using `ddply(...,summarise, ...)` inside a function.) This is a base solution that worked the way I expected:

```
descriptives_by_group <- function(dataset, group, x)
  {aggregate(dataset[[x]], dataset[group], function(x)
      c(  mean = mean(x),
          sd   = sd(x),
          min  = min(x),
          max  = max(x)
         ) )
  }

descriptives_by_group(mtcars, 'cyl', 'hp')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `as.quoted` function. Example below

```
simple_ddply <- function(dataset_name, variable_name){
    data <- ddply(dataset_name,as.quoted(variable_name), *remaining input)**
```

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of `quosures` in the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`), this becomes a bit more easier

```
library(dplyr)
descriptives_by_groupN <- function(dataset, group, x) {

   group <- enquo(group)
   x <- enquo(x)

  dataset %>%
         group_by(!!group) %>%
         summarise(Mean = mean(!!x),
                SD = sd(!!x),
                Min = min(!!x),
                Max = max(!!x))
}

descriptives_by_groupN(mtcars, cyl, hp)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
#   cyl      Mean       SD   Min   Max
#  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4  82.63636 20.93453    52   113
#2     6 122.28571 24.26049   105   175
#3     8 209.21429 50.97689   150   335
```

Here, the input arguments are converted to `quosures` with `enquo`, and inside the `group_by/summarise`, unquote the quosures (`!!` or `UQ`) to get it evaluated