# Alter values in one data frame based on comparison values in another in R

Tags: r, function, comparison, plyr, posixct

I am trying to subtract one hour to date/times within a POSIXct column that are earlier than or equal to a time stated in a different comparison dataframe for that particular ID.

For example:

```
#create sample data
Time<-as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-02 08:00:00","2015-11-02 11:00:00","2015-10-11 10:00:00","2015-11-11 09:00:00","2015-10-24 08:00:00","2015-10-27 08:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ID<-c(01,01,02,02,03,03)
data<-data.frame(Time,ID)
```

Which produces this:

```
                 Time ID
1 2015-10-02 08:00:00  1
2 2015-11-02 11:00:00  1
3 2015-10-11 10:00:00  2
4 2015-11-11 09:00:00  2
5 2015-10-24 08:00:00  3
6 2015-10-27 08:00:00  3
```

I then have another dataframe with a key date and time for each ID to compare against. The Time in data should be compared against Comparison in ComparisonData for the particular ID it is associated with. If the Time value in data is earlier than or equal to the comparison value one hour should be subtracted from the value in data:

```
#create sample comparison data
Comparison<-as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-29 08:00:00","2015-11-02 08:00:00","2015-10-26 08:30:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ID<-c(01,02,03)
ComparisonData<-data.frame(Comparison,ID)
```

This should look like this:

```
           Comparison  ID
1 2015-10-29 08:00:00   1
2 2015-11-02 08:00:00   2
3 2015-10-26 08:30:00   3
```

In summary, the code should check all times of a certain ID to see if any are earlier than or equal to the value specified in ComparisonData and if they are, subtract one hour. This should give this data frame as an output:

```
                 Time  ID
1 2015-10-02 07:00:00   1
2 2015-11-02 11:00:00   1
3 2015-10-11 09:00:00   2
4 2015-11-11 09:00:00   2
5 2015-10-24 07:00:00   3
6 2015-10-27 08:00:00   3
```

I have looked at similar solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728408/return-multiple-values-from-a-function-by-column-and-group-in-r?lq=1) but I cannot understand how to also check the times using the right timing with that particular ID.

I think ddply seems quite a promising option but I'm not sure how to use it for this particular problem.

Comment: What happens if you have several values which are earlier? They all should be modified?

Comment: yes, in fact, my actual dataset has over 60000 values which I know are earlier than the specified times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and efficient solution using `data.table`. First we join the two data sets by `ID` and then just modify the `Time`s which are lower or equal to `Comparison`

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(data)[ComparisonData, end := i.Comparison, on = "ID"]
data[Time <= end, Time := Time - 3600L][, end := NULL]
data
#                   Time ID
# 1: 2015-10-02 07:00:00  1
# 2: 2015-11-02 11:00:00  1
# 3: 2015-10-11 09:00:00  2
# 4: 2015-11-11 09:00:00  2
# 5: 2015-10-24 07:00:00  3
# 6: 2015-10-27 08:00:00  3
```

---

Alternatively, we could do this in one step while joining using `ifelse` (not sure how efficient this though)

```
setDT(data)[ComparisonData, 
            Time := ifelse(Time <= i.Comparison, 
                           Time - 3600L, Time), 
            on = "ID"]
data
#                   Time ID
# 1: 2015-10-02 07:00:00  1
# 2: 2015-11-02 11:00:00  1
# 3: 2015-10-11 09:00:00  2
# 4: 2015-11-11 09:00:00  2
# 5: 2015-10-24 07:00:00  3
# 6: 2015-10-27 08:00:00  3
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain your first solution a bit more? Especially where end and i.Comparison comes from (what does the i mean in this case?). I am also unsure of what is happening in the 3rd line with having two sets of square brackets? If this is just too basic can you direct me to somewhere that might explain it?

Comment: `i` means to get the `Comparison` column out of the `ComparisonData` data which is located in the `ith` argument of `data`.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) if you want to get familiar with `data.table` a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is going to be a better solution than this, however, I think this works.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(data$Time[i] < ComparisonData[data$ID[i], 1]){
   data$Time[i] <- data$Time[i] - 3600
  }
}



#          Time ID
#1 2015-10-02 07:00:00  1
#2 2015-11-02 11:00:00  1
#3 2015-10-11 09:00:00  2
#4 2015-11-11 09:00:00  2
#5 2015-10-24 07:00:00  3
#6 2015-10-27 08:00:00  3
```

This is going to iterate through every row in `data`.

`ComparisonData[data$ID[i], 1]` gets the `time` column in `ComparisonData` for the corresponding `ID`. If this is greater than the `Time` column in `data` then reduce the time by 1 hour.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more to how the if statement works as I am a bit confused. So in the first loop is will be: if 2015-10-02 08:00:00 < ???  how does it use ID?

Comment: @Christine have added an explanation. Let me know if something is not clear.