# Error in predict.svm(modelcold, cold) : object 'R_svmpredict' not found

Tags: r, svm, predict

I created an svm formula using my training data:

```
library(e1071)

modeltrain <- svm(Y~ X1 + as.factor(X2) + X3, data=traindata,
                  type="nu-regression",kernel="radial",cross=10, nu = 0.30, gamma=0.1)
```

Which I then use to generate predictions in my test data:

```
predict(modeltrain, testdata)
```

This has worked just fine on multiple machines, but when I send this formula to one of my collaborators and he tries to run the 'predict' function, he gets the following error:

> "Error in predict.svm(modelcold, cold) : object 'R_svmpredict' not found"

Note that:
- there is no missing in his test data
- all variables have been checked and they match the training data
- he has both the latest versions of R and Rtudio installed
- we've tried loading different versions of the model and restarting RStudio

I've searched online for help but the one answer I found was confusing:
[Object not found error when passing model formula to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function)

Frankly, we're both stumped. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

--- As requested, adding sessionInfo() output:

> R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    > LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] mgcv_1.8-20    nlme_3.1-131   e1071_1.6-8    dplyr_0.7.4    foreign_0.8-69
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     lattice_0.20-35  class_7.3-14     assertthat_0.2.0 > grid_3.4.2       R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     rlang_0.1.2      bindrcpp_0.2
>   [10] Matrix_1.2-11    tools_3.4.2      glue_1.1.1       compiler_3.4.2   >pkgconfig_2.0.1  bindr_0.1        tibble_1.3.4

Comment: Can you post the data so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Unfortunately no as the data is private. Here's the thing though, I can't reproduce this error on my computer but I've seen it on his. So I have no idea what the issue could be.

Comment: Can he reproduce the error with a different, publicly-available data set? Can he share his `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: As requested, here is the session info:

Comment: I don't see the `sessionInfo()`. Also, could he reproduce the error with another [dataset](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html)? This would help determine if it's a problem specific to the dataset, as opposed to the functions/packages.

Comment: Ok, updating my comment now. Was trying to run with another dataset and post before saving.

Comment: If he runs `e1071:::R_svmpredict` what output does he get?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your responses.
What ended up working was uninstalling the e1071 package and deleting the folder from the lib, and then reinstalling it again. Worked without a hitch.

Comment: My guess is that `R_svmpredict` – a C function called from the `e1071` package  – was (for some reason) missing. (It's hidden, hence the triple `:` to call it and see if it exists.)