# "Object not found" when calling lm within a function created by function factory

Tags: r, functional-programming, factory, environment, lm

I am attempting to build a general framework for quickly evaluating a variety of models. I am trying to use a factory pattern to generate "model trainer" functions that take a data frame and return a trained model. However, I am running into unexpected behavior of R's built-in `lm` function within this framework.

```
gen_lm_model_trainer <- function(formula, weights_col = NULL) {
  function(train_data) {
    trained_lm <- lm(formula = formula,
                     data = train_data,
                     weights = train_data[[weights_col]])

    pred_func <- function(test_data) {
      prediction <- predict(trained_lm, newdata = test_data)
      return(prediction)
    }

    return(list(predict = pred_func, info = trained_lm))
  }
}

mtcars$random_weights <- rbeta(nrow(mtcars), shape1 = 5, shape2 = 2)
trainer <- gen_lm_model_trainer(formula = mpg ~ ., weights_col = 'random_weights')
trained_model <- trainer(mtcars)
```

The response to this code is the following:

```
Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'train_data' not found
```

This is similar another SO question, [Object not found error when passing model formula to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function/36914542#36914542), but this problem is not solved by assigning the formula's environment to the generated function's environment, i.e.

```
gen_lm_model_trainer <- function(formula, weights_col = NULL) {
  function(train_data) {
    scoped_formula <- as.formula(formula, env = environment())
    trained_lm <- lm(formula = scoped_formula,
                     data = train_data,
                     weights = train_data[[weights_col]])

    pred_func <- function(test_data) {
      prediction <- predict(trained_lm, newdata = test_data)
      return(prediction)
    }

    return(list(predict = pred_func, info = trained_lm))
  }
}
```

A solution that works consistently for both problems would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial answer to the question -- partial in that it solves only this case and [not the linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function/36914542#36914542). The problem seems to be that lm's arguments are being evaluated in the environment that corresponds to calling `with(train_data, lm(...))`. It should therefore be safe to use `parent.frame()` to traverse to the environment of the calling function (the "model trainer"). This happens to correspond to a depth of n = 1 -- in this case, I think that n = 1 is the data frame's environment, n = 2 is eval's environment, and n = 3 is the environment from which `lm` is being called.

```
gen_lm_model_trainer <- function(formula, weights_col = NULL) {
  function(train_data) {
    trained_lm <- lm(formula = formula,
                     data = train_data,
                     weights = get('train_data', parent.frame(3))[[get('weights_col', parent.frame(3))]])

    pred_func <- function(test_data) {
      prediction <- predict(trained_lm, newdata = test_data)
      return(prediction)
    }

    return(list(predict = pred_func, info = trained_lm))
  }
}

mtcars$random_weights <- rbeta(nrow(mtcars), shape1 = 5, shape2 = 2)
trainer <- gen_lm_model_trainer(formula = mpg ~ ., weights_col = 'random_weights')
trained_model <- trainer(mtcars)
```

Why `lm` changes scope so unusually is unclear to me and seems like a bug.

Comment: I think if you look carefully, you'll discover that the method you've used is actually not successfully changing the environment of the formula. It works for me fine if I do `environment(formula) <- environment()` instead and just pass `formula` to `lm`. The method you used may only work when the formula begins as a character.

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer? I checked it and it seems like the best solution since it solves both problems.

Answer (score 0):

For interesting reasons adding

```
random_weights <- train_data[[weights_col]]
```

or, more generically

```
assign(weights_col, train_data[[weights_col]])
```

to the beginning of your `function(train_data) {` and passing the `random_weights` as `weights` to `lm` will fix this, resulting function looks like this:

```
gen_lm_model_trainer <- function(formula, weights_col = NULL) {
  function(train_data) {
    assign(weights_col, train_data[[weights_col]])
    trained_lm <- lm(formula = formula, data = train_data, weights = random_weights)

    pred_func <- function(test_data) {
      prediction <- predict(trained_lm, newdata = test_data)
      return(prediction)
    }

    return(list(predict = pred_func, info = trained_lm))
  }
}

mtcars$random_weights <- rbeta(nrow(mtcars), shape1 = 5, shape2 = 2)
trainer <- local(gen_lm_model_trainer(formula = mpg ~ ., weights_col = 'random_weights'))
trained_model <- trainer(mtcars)
```

**Reasoning:**

The underlying reason is that the weights are passed to `stats::model.frame.default` as part of `...` and that gets evaluated separately:

```
  env <- environment(formula)
  # ...
  # more code
  # ...
  extras <- substitute(list(...))
  extranames <- names(extras[-1L])
  extras <- eval(extras, data, env)
```

Comment: I think it is also sufficient to, instead of the `scoped_formula` attempt, replace that line with `environment(formula) <- environment()`, and just pass `formula` to `lm`.

Comment: @joran, indeed, I also think this is the most elegant solution, I would suggest making it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
gen_lm_model_trainer <- function(formula, weights_col = NULL) {
  function(train_data, .fml = formula, .wts = weights_col) {
    w <- train_data[[.wts]]
    environment(.fml) <- environment()
    trained_lm <- lm(formula = .fml,
                     data = train_data,
                     weights = w)
    pred_func <- function(test_data) {
      predict(trained_lm, newdata = test_data)
    }
  list(predict = pred_func, info = trained_lm)
  }
}

mtcars$random_weights <- rbeta(nrow(mtcars), shape1 = 5, shape2 = 2)
trainer <- gen_lm_model_trainer(formula = mpg ~ ., weights_col = 'random_weights')
trained_model <- trainer(mtcars)
```

I may have made some cosmetic changes but there are just two real changes:

1)
        environment(.fml) <- environment()
        # to make sure that the object within the function's scope are accessible 
        # otherwise it won't find the weights thing but curiously, it can find the data

2) Passing the formula and weights column names as arguments.

I can't quite explain why this combination works ... it's an interesting case. I've generated lm models with a different approach and there's always trouble with it.

Comment: If interested, I tried to explain why it can find the data but not the weights below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53891420/8876652 - weights are passed to `stats::model.frame.default` as part of `...` that gets different treatment.